# Why did MacVim try to connect to Vimium server?

Tags: macvim

So, I have installed Vimium today, and when I first relaunched MacVim, my Little Snitch showed that it tried to connect to `vimium.github.io`, which it never did before. Why did it do that and how has MacVim found out about Vimium in the first place?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues